# Using jQuery to close a Bootstrap modal that contains a partial view (MVC4)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I have a partial view that's displayed in a Bootstrap modal window. The view is an Ajax form used to create an instance of an object.

When I click the save button the object is added correctly to the database but the modal stays open. I want the modal to close when the save button is clicked.

The button in the modal:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-inverse" type="submit" id="btn-create-property-save">Save</button>
</div>
```

Then in my script file:

```
$('#btn-create-property-save').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#create-residential-property-modal').modal('hide');
    return false;
});
```

When I click the button, the modal remains open.

One thing I'm not too sure about, and which may be causing the problem, is what I'm returning in the `CreateObject` controller action. At the moment I just have `return PartialView();`. What should I be returning here given the scenario described above?

EDIT: Added code to show how modal is loaded.

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="create-residential-property-modal" data-url="@Url.Action("LandlordProperties", "Landlords")">
    <div id="create-property-container"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#show-create-property-modal').click(function () {
            var url = $('#create-residential-property-modal').data('url');

            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#create-property-container').html(data);

                $('#create-residential-property-modal').modal('show');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what is the name of modal? are you sure that it has the id"create-residential-property-modal"! check the source code that the browser provide.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I've done this in the past.

**Step 1, submit the form using Ajax:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", new AjaxOptions()
                      {
                          OnFailure = "Modal.onAjaxFailure",
                          OnSuccess = "Modal.onAjaxSuccess"
                      }))
    {     
        <div class="form-body">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Text, new { rows = "3" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-footer">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text)
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @CustomHelpers.SubmitButton("Add Comemnt")
        </div>
    }
```

**Step 2, return JSON result to display success/fail message:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CommentCreateModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           //Do your database insert etc here...

            return Json(new { error = false, message = "Comment added" });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { error = true, message = "The values entered are not valid" });
        }
    }
```

**Step 3, handle the response (my example is in TypeScript):**

```
export function onAjaxFailure(xhr, status, error) {
    //Show notifications for AJAX errors
    $.notify({
        type: "error",
        text: error
    });
}

export function onAjaxSuccess(data, status, xhr) {
    if (data.error) {
        $.notify({
            type: "error",
            text: data.message
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.modal').modal('hide'); //Hides modal window
        //Show message/anything else here
    }
}
```

Comment: Haven't got time to try this now, will let you know when I do.

Comment: Almost there, the modal window closes, but the screen still has the darkened effect that appears when the modal is first launched - any ideas on how to remedy this?

Comment: How are you loading the modal window? Can you update the original question with the js code.

Comment: Any idea on how to remove screen darkness on modal close?

Comment: Is this call "$.get(url, function (data)" returning a PartialView in the controller? If you don't return a PartialView, you will get a black overlay that doesn't go away on modal close.